# i cant add image to my new blog post in django

Tags: django-forms, django-templates

kindly help me, i am using class based views now am about to create new post using Createview i added all the fields including an image which stands for the thumbnail so if i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages/blog/new/ i get a form and if i fill in the fields and submit i get return back to the form saying the image fields is required meanwhile i already inserted an image , [this is the error in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrLhP.jpg)
and this is my code below

### views.py

```
class BlogCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Blog
    fields = ['title', 'categories', 'overview', 'thumbnail', 'summary']
```

### blog_form.html

```
<div class="content-section text-center">
     <form method="POST">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <fieldset class="form-group ">
             <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 h2">Blog Post</legend>
             {{ form|crispy }}
         </fieldset>
         <div class="form-group">
             <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>

         </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form, so:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

See detailed explanation is this elaborate answer:
[What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)